# use python twisted framework to connect to multiple serial sockets

Tags: python, serial-port, twisted

I currently use twisted to connect to a serial device I have, using code like the following.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
SerialPort(Handler(), "/dev/ttyACM1", reactor, baudrate='9600')
reactor.run()
```

However, I know need to extend the application to monitor for new serial devices being added (and removed).  I currently use pyinotify to look for new devices being added/removed, and this seems to work well.

```
class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        ... connect to serial device
        ...
```

At the moment I seem to have several problems.  The biggest I think is that I just don't know enough about Twisted to know what the 'correct' way of doing this is.

Currently as I have it, the pyinotify event handler kicks of in a separate thread, meaning the reactor is not running in the main thread.  Is this an issue?

Once the first device is connected, I struggle to add a second - not least the reactor is already running by the time the second device is added.  Even if I protect that with a

```
if not reactor.running:
```

the second connection doesn't add to the reactor properly (at least connectionMade, dataReceived received methods don't fire).

If I start the reactor first, then let the pyinotify events try and add to the running reactor this doesn't seem to work either - the device does connect, but the dataReceived method never gets called.

Basically, I'm sure there is a neat recipe for getting this to work, I just haven't been able to find it, either through Google or trial and error.  Can anybody suggest to me how I might be able to get this working?

Thanks in advance for any help you're able to offer,

Simon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you want to use a Twisted API but your code isn't running in the same thread as the reactor, you can use `reactor.callFromThread` to have the reactor call some of your code in its thread.  So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
    reactor.callFromThread(
        SerialPort, Handler(), "/dev/ttyACM1", reactor, baudrate='9600')
```

However, you also don't need to have any extra threads to do what you described.  Instead of using `pyinotify`, use `twisted.internet.inotify`:

```
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
from twisted.internet.inotify import IN_CREATE, INotify
from twisted.internet import reactor

def created(ignored, path, mask):
    SerialPort(
        Handler(),
        "/dev/ttyACM1", # Or... use `path` here?
        reactor, baudrate='9600')

notifier = INotify()
notifier.watch(FilePath("/some/directory"), IN_CREATE, callbacks=[created])
notifier.startReading()

reactor.run()
```